# jquery .load not working with function parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, load

I have an onLoad method in my html body that is calling a function to load certain data based on the php variables in my url.

```
body onLoad="getData(<?php echo $_GET['Category']; ?>, <?php echo $_GET['Product']; ?>);"
```

This is my onLoad call: Which when I check googles chrome inspect element it is displaying the two variables names when i run the page.

```
function getData(Category, Product){
            $('.products').load('test.php');
            return;
        }
```

My function is this but for some reason if I pass in the parameters onload from above it does not work but if i use getData() with no variables it runs. Im not understanding why if the variables are used its not running the .load. Am I not calling the URL variables correctly in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to wrap your variables in quotes if they are strings:

`body onLoad="getData('<?php echo $_GET['Category']; ?>', '<?php echo $_GET['Product']; ?>');"`

Comment: Sweet thank you that did it! I was struggling with that for the last two hours and I couldn't figure out why!